# Treatment validation on mouse models

Tags: cancer, snp, mice

I am struggling to set up a project proposal for validation of a known treatment for metastatic colorectal cancer in mouse models.
I want to see how SNPs in patients contribute to their drug resistance and/or toxicity. For the validation of these SNPs as predictive biomarkers, I will use cell lines and mouse models. But, how am I supposed to "induce" these specific SNPs in the mice? CRISPR/Cas9 can be used for the alteration of bigger parts. 
Any idea is a useful idea!